# Laravel 5.5 update image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'v created a form to update the table 'organizer'. My problem is that the image wont update. I've already added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form.

If I set the validation of the image to required, laravel throwes the error "The logo must be an image". It seems that my ImageController doesn't get the image file . But why does the Controller get all the other data like the description, name ..?

All the other data in the table 'organizer' is updating without problems!

Form

```
    <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/organizer/update/{{ $organizer->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        ...
        other input fields...
        ...
        <label>Logo</label>
        <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" accept="image/*"/>

        <button class="btn-add" type="submit">@lang('Save')</button>
        </form>
```

Controller (only the code for updating the image)

```
        if($request->hasFile('logo')){
        // ADD NEW lOGO
        $logo = $request->file('logo');
        $logo_name = $request->name.'_logo'.time().'.'.$logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->logo->move($destinationPath, $logo_name);
        $oldFilename = $organizer->logo;
        // UPDATE DATABASE
        $organizer->logo = $logo_name;
        // DELETE OLD lOGO
        Storage::disk('public')->delete("organizer/$oldFilename.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: The first step is to verify what exactly the controller is receiving when the form is submitted, then from there you can continue with debugging. At the top of your controller place `dd($request->logo);` and then submit your form. What does that output?

Comment: Please post your backend validation code

Comment: `method="POST"` is missing in your form tag

Comment: @sam The output seems to be ok. I get the name of the file with the .jpg extension...

Comment: That is not the result you would expect, if a file has been uploaded correctly then you would expect to see an `UploadedFile` object. The problem is as @linktoahref stated: you're missing `method="post"` from your form, without that it is submitting a GET request.

Comment: @Paras I use the standard validation of laravel with 'logo' => 'image'...

Comment: @sam But I can't use the method="Post" because I have to use the put method for updating in laravel

Comment: That's not how form submission works. You must always provide `method="post"`. HTML forms *do not* support `PUT` so what Laravel does is, behind the scenes, when you submit a `POST` request with the `_method` field, it changes (internally) the method from `POST` to `PUT`. Your form should have *both* the method *and* the method_field helper. So <form method="post" action="/">{{ method_field('put') }}</form>. Read the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-method-field

Comment: @sam When I add method="POST" laravel throwes MethodNotAllowedHttpException. I had this problem also at my create form, but there I solved the issue by removing method="POST" ..

Comment: You need to set your Route to `put`, e.g: `Route::put('/organizer/update/{id}', '...');`

Comment: @sam THANK YOU.. Route::put('/organizer/update/{id}', '...') solved it !!